# how to apply checkbox in multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to apply checkbox in the multiselect dropdown but not the success. I am creating multi-select dropdown using send form. but not apply checkbox in this multi-select dropdown. so please help

```
<?php
    echo $this->formSelect(
        'ctr_partnerId',
        $expPartId,
        array(
            'class' => 'select_input',
            'multiple' => true,
            'size' => 10
        ),
        $this->usrName
    );
?>
```

I am using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $('select[multiple]').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am also use <script>
                $('#ctr_partnerId').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
            });
</script> but not success.

Comment: show your browser rendered html

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with your html because it's working perfect for me

use unique selector use `select[name="ss"]` or `id`

```js
$('select[name="ss"]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
            });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>



<select name="ss" class="select_input" multiple >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```